# Bind to domain failed: can't contact LDAP server

Tags: active-directory, freeradius

I'm trying to authenticate my users created in Active Directory through FreeRADIUS server but I get an Access-Reject and the debug shows the following:

```
bind to imendab.com:389 failed : can't contact LDAP server.
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a network level issue rather than a problem with FreeRADIUS.

Make sure your LDAP server is running and listening on TCP port 389 (not just LDAPS on port 636). Make sure it is not firewalled. Check what's happening with tcpdump or similar packet trace, and try command-line LDAP tools on the RADIUS server to make sure that they can do a successful look up.

Note that usually to authenticate users against Active Directory you need to install Samba on the FreeRADIUS server and join it to the domain. You can't get password hashes out of AD over LDAP. The only exception is if you are using some kind of PAP method (e.g. plain PAP or EAP-TTLS/PAP).